# Failure when processing annotations for application.The error is Conflict found while merging web fragment

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am having an application which works fine with version prior to 
`WebLogic-12.2.1.2` but once I upgrade to `WebLogic 12.2.1.2` It throws the following exception.

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7740fbd5() : Version>
<Aug 28, 2017, 3:49:13,275 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "881239794681866" for task "3" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.MergeException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7740fbd5() : Version"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.MergeException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7740fbd5() : Version
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.MergeException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7740fbd5() : Version
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.GeneralRuleMerger.handleChangeEvent(GeneralRuleMerger.java:58)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.AbstractMerger.merge(AbstractMerger.java:15)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentMergeDispatcher.merge(WebFragmentMergeDispatcher.java:61)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentManager.mergeFragment(WebFragmentManager.java:245)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:122)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Aug 28, 2017, 3:49:13,296 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "***".>
<Aug 28, 2017, 3:49:13,296 PM IST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.MergeException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7740fbd5() : Version
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.MergeException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7740fbd5() : Version
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.GeneralRuleMerger.handleChangeEvent(GeneralRuleMerger.java:58)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.AbstractMerger.merge(AbstractMerger.java:15)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentMergeDispatcher.merge(WebFragmentMergeDispatcher.java:61)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentManager.mergeFragment(WebFragmentManager.java:245)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:122)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Aug 28, 2017, 3:49:13,309 PM IST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.MergeException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7740fbd5() : Version
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:727)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:239)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:103)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:241)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:794)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1340)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:267)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.MergeException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7740fbd5() : Version
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.GeneralRuleMerger.handleChangeEvent(GeneralRuleMerger.java:58)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.AbstractMerger.merge(AbstractMerger.java:15)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentMergeDispatcher.merge(WebFragmentMergeDispatcher.java:61)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.fragment.WebFragmentManager.mergeFragment(WebFragmentManager.java:245)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:122)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:105)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processAnnotations(WebAppModule.java:1975)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processAnnotations(WebAppModule.java:1937)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:800)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
>
<Aug 28, 2017, 3:49:13,475 PM IST> <Warning> <Munger> <BEA-2156203> <A version attribute was not found in element "web-app" in the deployment descriptor /u01/***/***/webapps/***/WEB-INF/web.xml. A version attribute is required, but this version of the WebLogic Server will assume that the latest version is used. Future versions of WebLogic Server will reject descriptors that do not specify the Java EE version. To eliminate this warning, add an appropriate "version=" to element "web-app" in the deployment descriptor.>
<Aug 28, 2017, 3:49:13,617 PM IST> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.>
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7b55af1f() : Version
at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.processAnnotations(WARModule.java:504)
at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.processAnnotations(WARModule.java:589)
at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.merge(WARModule.java:537)
at weblogic.application.compiler.ToolsModuleWrapper.merge(ToolsModuleWrapper.java:96)
at weblogic.application.utils.CustomModuleManager.merge(CustomModuleManager.java:78)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleMergeFlow.proecessModule(SingleModuleMergeFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleFlow.compile(SingleModuleFlow.java:64)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.compiler.BaseMerger.merge(BaseMerger.java:20)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:75)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:40)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:146)
at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:158)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:94)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:58)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:186)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:167)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initialize(SessionHelper.java:847)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:668)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:656)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:739)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper$1.execute(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:860)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5646)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.initDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:848)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.completeInitialization(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:444)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:151)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:104)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:65)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.getPersistenceUnitNames(PersistenceUtils.java:76)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.hasPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUtils.java:52)
at com.bea.console.utils.AppDeploymentBackingFile.preRender(AppDeploymentBackingFile.java:131)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.Backable$Impl.preRender(Backable.java:191)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.AdministeredBackableControl.preRender(AdministeredBackableControl.java:104)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.window.Window.preRender(Window.java:445)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.page.Page.preRender(Page.java:239)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$6.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:428)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:727)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:146)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:231)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:216)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at com.bea.console.internal.ParamFilter.doFilter(ParamFilter.java:38)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
<Aug 28, 2017, 3:49:13,621 PM IST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: java.io.IOException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7b55af1f() : Version
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:65)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:186)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:167)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initialize(SessionHelper.java:847)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:668)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:656)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:739)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper$1.execute(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:860)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5646)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.initDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:848)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.completeInitialization(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:444)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:151)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:104)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:65)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.getPersistenceUnitNames(PersistenceUtils.java:76)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.hasPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUtils.java:52)
at com.bea.console.utils.AppDeploymentBackingFile.preRender(AppDeploymentBackingFile.java:131)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.Backable$Impl.preRender(Backable.java:191)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.AdministeredBackableControl.preRender(AdministeredBackableControl.java:104)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.window.Window.preRender(Window.java:445)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.page.Page.preRender(Page.java:239)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$6.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:428)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:727)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:146)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:231)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:216)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at com.bea.console.internal.ParamFilter.doFilter(ParamFilter.java:38)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: Conflict found while merging web fragment, weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.WebFragmentBeanImpl@7b55af1f() : Version
at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.processAnnotations(WARModule.java:504)
at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.processAnnotations(WARModule.java:589)
at weblogic.servlet.tools.WARModule.merge(WARModule.java:537)
at weblogic.application.compiler.ToolsModuleWrapper.merge(ToolsModuleWrapper.java:96)
at weblogic.application.utils.CustomModuleManager.merge(CustomModuleManager.java:78)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleMergeFlow.proecessModule(SingleModuleMergeFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleFlow.compile(SingleModuleFlow.java:64)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.compiler.BaseMerger.merge(BaseMerger.java:20)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:75)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:40)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:146)
at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:158)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:94)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:58)
... 78 more
>
```

**I actually include a project in my application** which uses `servlet-api 3.0`(to use some functionality of Async servlet) and I am using `servlet-api 2.4` in my application. Also the application doesn't have any web-fragment concept.
Can there be any conflicts because of this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can anybody reply?

Answer (score 2):

Weblogic 12c onwards, the jars are scanned for presence of web fragments and then merged with the application's web.xml.If your application web.xml or other jars web-fragment.xml have diferent DTD version then this issue will come.Need to make all DTD version quals.

Comment: Post this as a comment rather than making it as an Answer. An answer should contain a detailed explanation along with some codes if any.